# Discord oAuth with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0

so for the past day I have been trying to implement discord oAuth into a react native app to no avail. I tried with the react-native-app-auth package but get the error `null is not an object (evaluating 'RNAppAuth.authorize')` with the code of

```
    const config = {
        clientId: '[REDACTED]',
        clientSecret: '[REDACTED]',
        redirectUrl: '[REDACTED]',
        scopes: ['identify'],
        serviceConfiguration: {
          authorizationEndpoint: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[REDACTED]&redirect_uri=[REDACTED]',
          tokenEndpoint: 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token',
          revocationEndpoint: 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token/revoke'
        }
      }
    try {
        const authResult = await authorize(config)
        console.log(authResult)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

And then I tried the expo authentication method but that one didn't work at all, can someone please help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Running an expo proj with expo 42.0.1, react 16.13.1, and react native 42.0.0.